# Query to merge simplified polygons according to the map scale-factor

Tags: postgis, polygon, query, simplify, scale-factor

I'm trying to construct a view in PostgreSQL that simplify polygons according to the map scale-factor. Basically I was reading this thread http://linfiniti.com/2011/06/scale-dependent-generalization-in-postgis-and-qgis/ and I managed how to do it in QGIS, but about POstGIS I was rather confused. Can someone highlight me?

Another detail, I already have three different tables each one at a different simplified vision. I just need a query that assembly these ones declaring the factor scale for each one.

Comment: How are you rendering the data - through a wms/wfs/direct to postgis??

Can't you just set in QGIS to display each layer at the appropriate zoom?

Comment: I can set it in QGIS, but it's not enough. I need a WMS layer to load in Geoserver. 
I need a single layer whether a shapefile or a query into PostGIS.

Comment: So are you needing PostGIS to alter the simplification of a dataset, served through GeoServer based upon the zoom level of the WMS rendered by QGIS?

Comment: not necessary the zoom level must be from QGIS. I used QGIS only to have an idea of the final result. The aim is a query that merges the 3 (or even more) tables (that I already have in PostGIS) each one with a different level of simplification. Once I have this query I can decide how to pass this to Geoserver: as a shapefile or a PostGIS layer. I apologize for maybe repeating myself, but I'm not too skilled with GIS softwares & Co.